# urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused in python when connecting from one VM to another

Tags: python, mongodb, urllib2

I am testing out a script in python that saves some arbitrary values in a mongo database. This script runs on one Virtual Machine and the mongo db runs on another Virtual Machine. While testing localy (without deployidng my code to the VMs) everything worked perfectly but since I started testing on the VMs I get this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1169, in do_open raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

I try to connect to the mongo VM by using this code snippet:

```
import os, pyjsonrpc
storeClient = pyjsonrpc.HttpClient(
   url = os.getenv("URL_DATASTORE", "http://localhost:8081/jsonrpc/"),
   username = "",
   password = "")
```

I can ping my mongodb VM with no problem from my script VM but the moment I try to connect via the storeClient I get the `urllib2` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made sure the two VMs can reach one another at all? Is the firewall permitting connections to port 8081?

Comment: Try doing the same HTTP request from the command line using `curl` or `wget`

Comment: @MartijnPieters i can ping the datastore VM with no problem from the datasource VM (where the script is running)

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa how would I do that? Sorry, m quite new using command line :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the wrong server:

```
url = os.getenv("URL_DATASTORE", "http://localhost:8081/jsonrpc/"),
#                                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

You are running it on a different VM, not localhost.

Comment: You are right. This was my problem. It was not me who set up the VMs so I blindly used the code that worked for me localy. By replacing localhost with the IP of the mongo VM, I am able to save data to the database. It is a stupid mistake but it took me about 6 hours and your well placed remark to correct it. Thank you very much :D

Comment: @GeorgiNikolov: if this happens again (you get stuck), I recommend [getting yourself a rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). It is amazing how often explaining everything in detail brings out little issues like these.